# MySQL 5.5: "Free space" reserved for table?

Tags: mysql, innodb

On the same MySQL (v. 5.5) service i have multiple database.

One of this databases has a table with 29'000'000 records (3.3 GiB).

When i delete some records, MySQL seems reserve the free space only for the current table. I see into table inspector ([MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/it/products/workbench/)): Data Free 1.4 GiB.

[image]

I'm wrong or the space used by a table is never reused by other table or other database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike some other engines, InnoDB does not generally reclaim free space, meaning your tables, once at a certain size, remain there pretty much perpetually. One way to recover this space is the somewhat painful `OPTIMIZE TABLE` command which can rebuild and reindex the table, freeing that up.

This does lock the table for the duration and on large tables can take hours, so use carefully.

Comment: thanks for the reply. This happen even if i drop the table?

Comment: If you drop the table and you're using the [`file_per_table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-multiple-tablespaces.html) option then it should free up the space.

Answer (score 2):

You commented that you are not using `innnodb_file_per_table=1`, you should know that the "Data free" is the amount of free space in the whole tablespace (`ibdata1`).

- If you use `innodb_file_per_table=1`, then each tablespace would have exactly one table, and the free space reported would be for that tablespace. In that mode, the "Data free" would be available only for the single table stored in that tablespace.
- If you use `innodb_file_per_table=0`, then all tables share a common system tablespace (called `ibdata1` by default). The "Data free" is available to be used by any table in that tablespace. For example, if you delete from or drop a table, the space freed up may be used by one or more different tables automatically. You don't have to do anything to reallocate the space to other tables.

  Even though the "Data free" appears to be shown for each table, the actual free space is NOT dedicated per table, nor is it multiplied by the number of tables you have.

  In short, it's free space per *tablespace*, not per table.

Only completely **free extents** are counted in "Data free". An extent is a 1MB chunk of data pages. In other words, 64 contiguous pages, each 16KB in size by default. There may be other free pages in the tablespace in smaller groups. There may also be some free space within individual pages. Neither of these are not included in the "Data free" statistic.